# get product item category and attribute_set name and id in order export

Tags: magento-1.9, export, attribute-set, category-products

I am trying to modify [order export extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-jalappeno-order-export.html) 
I Wan to include product item category_id, category_name, attribute_set in the export array.

Current array look like this

```
protected function getOrderItemValues($item, $order, $itemInc=1) 
{

    return array(
        $itemInc,
        $item->getName(),
        $item->getStatus(),
        $this->getItemSku($item),
        $this->getItemOptions($item),
        $this->formatPrice($item->getOriginalPrice(), $order),
        $this->formatPrice($item->getData('price'), $order),
        (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(),
        (int)$item->getQtyInvoiced(),
        (int)$item->getQtyShipped(),
        (int)$item->getQtyCanceled(),
        (int)$item->getQtyRefunded(),
        $this->formatPrice($item->getTaxAmount(), $order),
        $this->formatPrice($item->getDiscountAmount(), $order),
        $this->formatPrice($this->getItemTotal($item), $order)
    );
}
```

Is there a method like `$this->getItemCategory($item),` or getAttribute etc in magento which i can use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

$product = $item->getProduct();

$attribute_set = $product->getAttributeSetId();

$category_id = $product->getCategoryIds();

Comment: hi Brian, that in case of $category_id returns another array. So i get output Like 'Array' , how to get the actual value ?